# Calculating Knn in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn

I would like to write a function to return a number of containing the majority category.

I wrote the following function to calculate the distances.

**distance** **metric** given (Euclid, Manthan, et).

**xTrainInstances** - is a data frame including all train instances

**xSeriesTestVector** - is a Series object, from the test set

```
 def calc_distances(xSeriesTestVector, xTrainInstances, distanceMetric):
 distances = np.zeros(xTrainInstances.shape[0])
 for i in range(xTrainInstances.shape[0]):
    distances[i] = distanceMetric(xSeriesTestVector, xTrainInstances.iloc[i])
return distances
```

suppose I Have the following Dataframe, The survived column is my category.

```
                    Survived
 PassengerId          
    1                   0
    2                   1
    3                   1
    4                   1
    5                   0
```

***My Question***

I would like to know how to implement the following function?
I got stuck,distances returns me an array of distances,from predict_one_instance,I would like to return the correct category

- xSeriesTestVector - is a Series object, from the test set to be classified
- **xTrainInstances** - a dataframe including all train instances to be compared to
- **yTrainCategories** - a dataframe including all train categories
- **distanceMetric** - the name of the distance function, not as a string
- **k** - the number of Nearest Neighbors (we select the majority out of k votes)

  ```
                      Pclass  SibSp  Parch     Fare   Age
       pid
       1                 3      1      0   7.2500  22.0
       2                 1      1      0  71.2833  38.0
       3                 3      0      0   7.9250  26.0
       4                 1      1      0  53.1000  35.0
       5                 3      0      0   8.0500  35.0
                       Pclass  SibSp  Parch     Fare   Age
       pid
       1                 3      1      0   7.2500  22.0
       2                 1      1      0  71.2833  38.0
       3                 3      0      0   7.9250  26.0
       4                 1      1      0  53.1000  35.0
       5                 3      0      0   8.0500  35.0


      def predict_one_instance(xSeriesTestVector, 
          xTrainInstances,yTrainCategories,distanceMetric,k):

          distances = calc_distances(xSeriesTestVector, xTrainInstances,distanceMetric)
  ```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I understand that you got stuck, but what part of your implementation of predict_one_instance isn't working for you?

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this example, using the 'manhattan'

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data"

# Assign colum names to the dataset
names = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width', 'Class']

# Read dataset to pandas dataframe
dataset = pd.read_csv(url, names=names)


dataset.head()


X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20)


from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)

X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)


from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, metric='manhattan')
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)


y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)


from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

Three mostly similar, but slightly different results

```
# manhattan
                 precision    recall  f1-score   support

    Iris-setosa       1.00      1.00      1.00         9
Iris-versicolor       1.00      1.00      1.00        15
 Iris-virginica       1.00      1.00      1.00         6

       accuracy                           1.00        30
      macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00        30
   weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00        30


# euclidian
                 precision    recall  f1-score   support

    Iris-setosa       1.00      1.00      1.00        11
Iris-versicolor       0.90      1.00      0.95         9
 Iris-virginica       1.00      0.90      0.95        10

       accuracy                           0.97        30
      macro avg       0.97      0.97      0.96        30
   weighted avg       0.97      0.97      0.97        30


# minkowski
                 precision    recall  f1-score   support

    Iris-setosa       1.00      1.00      1.00        13
Iris-versicolor       1.00      0.85      0.92        13
 Iris-virginica       0.67      1.00      0.80         4

       accuracy                           0.93        30
      macro avg       0.89      0.95      0.91        30
   weighted avg       0.96      0.93      0.94        30
```

Just change the metric when you run these 3 examples (you can easily loop through these three items in a list to automate the entire process):

```
metric='manhattan'
metric='euclidian'
metric='minkowski'
```

Resource:

https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/scikit-learn/scikit_machine_learning_k-NN_k-nearest-neighbors-algorithm.php